# Mathematical question: numbering table cells by rows

Tags: html

I have an HTML table like this:

[image: table]

There are 27 tr elements here, which are arranged in three-thirds of columns.

I want to number the trs according to their position in the table from top to bottom. Thus, element 1 will be numbered 1, and so will elements 4 and 7, because they are the first row in the table; Element 2 will be 2 as well as 5 and 8;... 21 will be 9, as well as 24 and 27, because they are the ninth row.

I have several ways to do this in JS but for me they are "manual". There must be a simple mathematical function that will produce the desired output.

The HTML code (although not so relevant):

```
<table dir="auto" style="
    height: 400;
    width: 400;
    border-color: azure;
    border-width: 3;
">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <table>
          <tbody data-general-square="1">
            <tr data-column="1">1</tr>
            <tr data-column="2">2</tr>
            <tr data-column="3">3</tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </th>
      <th>
        <table>
          <tbody data-general-square="2">
            <tr data-column="4">4</tr>
            <tr data-column="5">5</tr>
            <tr data-column="6">6</tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </th>
      <th>
        <table>
          <tbody data-general-square="3">
            <tr data-column="7">7</tr>
            <tr data-column="8">8</tr>
            <tr data-column="9">9</tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <table>
          <tbody data-general-square="4">
            <tr data-column="10">10</tr>
            <tr data-column="11">11</tr>
            <tr data-column="12">12</tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </th>
      <th>
        <table>
          <tbody data-general-square="5">
            <tr data-column="13">13</tr>
            <tr data-column="14">14</tr>
            <tr data-column="15">15</tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </th>
      <th>
        <table>
          <tbody data-general-square="6">
            <tr data-column="16">16</tr>
            <tr data-column="17">17</tr>
            <tr data-column="18">18</tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <table>
          <tbody data-general-square="7">
            <tr data-column="19">19</tr>
            <tr data-column="20">20</tr>
            <tr data-column="21">21</tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </th>
      <th>
        <table>
          <tbody data-general-square="8">
            <tr data-column="22">22</tr>
            <tr data-column="23">23</tr>
            <tr data-column="24">24</tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </th>
      <th>
        <table>
          <tbody data-general-square="9">
            <tr data-column="25">25</tr>
            <tr data-column="26">26</tr>
            <tr data-column="27">27</tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: you can add script javascript

Comment: What do you mean by 'simple mathematical function'?

Comment: Did you forget the `<td>` elements in which the contents (the numbers) should appear; a `<tr>` element has no valid children except for `<td>` or `<th>`; all content must be in one of those. Further, are the nested `<table>` elements there for a specific reason?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: For some reason, they did understand me here https://tchumim.com/post/152847.  And I got an excellent answer. (Translate this by Google).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear about what *exactly* you want the output to be or what you mean by number the tr elements.

If you want to add a `data-row` attribute to every cell, you'll likely need to nest some loops (in PHP, for example) to output the HTML.

If you want to add the number to be displayed inside the cell, this could be done with PHP loops or with CSS pseudo-elements. You could also style each row with CSS pseudo-classes.

However, these suggestions are probably what you'd consider "manual", so I don't understand what you are wanting to output with 3x3 grid calculations that can be done using JavaScript.

BTW, you can't put data directly in `tr` row elements. Your example is missing the `td` cells. Additionally, your CSS for the table has height, width, and border lengths, but is missing the unit and border style.

```
<table>
  <tbody>
<?php 
 
$loop = $square = $row = $column = 0;
$loop++;

for ($loop1=1; $loop1 <= 3; $loop1++) {
  echo "    <tr>\n";
  
  for ($loop2=1; $loop2 <= 3; $loop2++) {
    $square++;
    echo "      <th>\n        <table>\n          <tbody data-general-square=\"$square\">\n";
      $row=$loop;
      
    for ($loop3=1; $loop3 <= 3; $loop3++) {
      $column++;
      echo "            <tr data-column=\"$column\" data-row=\"$row\"><td>Row $row: $column</td></tr>\n";
      $row++;
    }
    
    echo "          </tbody>\n        </table>\n      </th>\n";
  }
  
  echo "    </tr>\n";
  $loop+=3;
}
?>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Those nested PHP loops output this HTML:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <table>
          <tbody data-general-square="1">
            <tr data-column="1" data-row="1"><td>Row 1: 1</td></tr>
            <tr data-column="2" data-row="2"><td>Row 2: 2</td></tr>
            <tr data-column="3" data-row="3"><td>Row 3: 3</td></tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </th>
      <th>
        <table>
          <tbody data-general-square="2">
            <tr data-column="4" data-row="1"><td>Row 1: 4</td></tr>
            <tr data-column="5" data-row="2"><td>Row 2: 5</td></tr>
            <tr data-column="6" data-row="3"><td>Row 3: 6</td></tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </th>
      <th>
        <table>
          <tbody data-general-square="3">
            <tr data-column="7" data-row="1"><td>Row 1: 7</td></tr>
            <tr data-column="8" data-row="2"><td>Row 2: 8</td></tr>
            <tr data-column="9" data-row="3"><td>Row 3: 9</td></tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <table>
          <tbody data-general-square="4">
            <tr data-column="10" data-row="4"><td>Row 4: 10</td></tr>
            <tr data-column="11" data-row="5"><td>Row 5: 11</td></tr>
            <tr data-column="12" data-row="6"><td>Row 6: 12</td></tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </th>
      <th>
        <table>
          <tbody data-general-square="5">
            <tr data-column="13" data-row="4"><td>Row 4: 13</td></tr>
            <tr data-column="14" data-row="5"><td>Row 5: 14</td></tr>
            <tr data-column="15" data-row="6"><td>Row 6: 15</td></tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </th>
      <th>
        <table>
          <tbody data-general-square="6">
            <tr data-column="16" data-row="4"><td>Row 4: 16</td></tr>
            <tr data-column="17" data-row="5"><td>Row 5: 17</td></tr>
            <tr data-column="18" data-row="6"><td>Row 6: 18</td></tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <table>
          <tbody data-general-square="7">
            <tr data-column="19" data-row="7"><td>Row 7: 19</td></tr>
            <tr data-column="20" data-row="8"><td>Row 8: 20</td></tr>
            <tr data-column="21" data-row="9"><td>Row 9: 21</td></tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </th>
      <th>
        <table>
          <tbody data-general-square="8">
            <tr data-column="22" data-row="7"><td>Row 7: 22</td></tr>
            <tr data-column="23" data-row="8"><td>Row 8: 23</td></tr>
            <tr data-column="24" data-row="9"><td>Row 9: 24</td></tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </th>
      <th>
        <table>
          <tbody data-general-square="9">
            <tr data-column="25" data-row="7"><td>Row 7: 25</td></tr>
            <tr data-column="26" data-row="8"><td>Row 8: 26</td></tr>
            <tr data-column="27" data-row="9"><td>Row 9: 27</td></tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </th>
    </tr>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Example using CSS pseudo-element and pseudo-classe:

```css
tr:nth-of-type(1) tr:nth-of-type(1) td:before {content: "Row 1: "}
tr:nth-of-type(2) tr:nth-of-type(3) td:before {content: "Row 6: "}
tr:nth-of-type(3) tr:nth-of-type(2) td:before {content: "Row 8: "}

tr:nth-of-type(1) tr:nth-of-type(1) {background-color: gold}
tr:nth-of-type(2) tr:nth-of-type(3) {background-color: silver}
tr:nth-of-type(3) tr:nth-of-type(2) {background-color: chocolate}
```

```html
<table dir="auto" style="
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    border-color: azure;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-style: solid;
">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <table>
          <tbody data-general-square="1">
            <tr data-column="1"><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr data-column="2"><td>2</td></tr>
            <tr data-column="3"><td>3</td></tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </th>
      <th>
        <table>
          <tbody data-general-square="2">
            <tr data-column="4"><td>4</td></tr>
            <tr data-column="5"><td>5</td></tr>
            <tr data-column="6"><td>6</td></tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </th>
      <th>
        <table>
          <tbody data-general-square="3">
            <tr data-column="7"><td>7</td></tr>
            <tr data-column="8"><td>8</td></tr>
            <tr data-column="9"><td>9</td></tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </th>
     </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <table>
          <tbody data-general-square="4">
            <tr data-column="10"><td>10</td></tr>
            <tr data-column="11"><td>11</td></tr>
            <tr data-column="12"><td>12</td></tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </th>
      <th>
        <table>
          <tbody data-general-square="5">
            <tr data-column="13"><td>13</td></tr>
            <tr data-column="14"><td>14</td></tr>
            <tr data-column="15"><td>15</td></tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </th>
      <th>
        <table>
          <tbody data-general-square="6">
            <tr data-column="16"><td>16</td></tr>
            <tr data-column="17"><td>17</td></tr>
            <tr data-column="18"><td>18</td></tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </th>
   </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <table>
          <tbody data-general-square="7">
            <tr data-column="19"><td>19</td></tr>
            <tr data-column="20"><td>20</td></tr>
            <tr data-column="21"><td>21</td></tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </th>
      <th>
        <table>
          <tbody data-general-square="8">
            <tr data-column="22"><td>22</td></tr>
            <tr data-column="23"><td>23</td></tr>
            <tr data-column="24"><td>24</td></tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </th>
      <th>
        <table>
          <tbody data-general-square="9">
            <tr data-column="25"><td>25</td></tr>
            <tr data-column="26"><td>26</td></tr>
            <tr data-column="27"><td>27</td></tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </th>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```